# Get matched subset and count of subset in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following document structure

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("578a14112acb483c1a0dce0a"),
    "professionalInterests" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("578a063a0068ec0c1320a1de"),
            "interestName" : "Finance and Accounting"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("578a063a0068ec0c1320a1e7"), 
            "interestName" : "Journalism and Mass Media"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("578a063a0068ec0c1320a1e5"),
            "interestName" : "Manufacturing Industry"
        }
    ],
    "personalInterests" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("578a063a0068ec0c1320a1d2"),
            "interestName" : "Music"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("578a063a0068ec0c1320a1d4"),
            "interestName" : "Sports"
        }
    ]
}
```

and I have some interests array like

```
var professionalInterests = [ 
            {
                "interestName" : "Finance and Accounting"
            }
];
var personalInterests  = [ 
            {
                "interestName" : "Music"
            }
];
```

I want to retrieve all documents but sorted by matched "professional interests" and "professional interests" with the matched count. 
I tried `$setIntersection` but it doesn't work for me.
I also tried through `$unwind`, `$project`, `$size` but it's not effective solution. 
Resulted document should contain but sorting depend upon the matched interest(like if with "userA" 2 interests matched and "userB" 3 interests matched then "userB" is above in the list then "userA".

```
{
   professionalInterests : [],//user professional interests
   personalInterests : [],//user personal interest
   matchedProfessionalInterests : [],// contain the matched professional interest
   matchedPersonalInterests : [],// contain the matched personal interest
   matchedProfessionalInterestsCount : number,
   matchedPersonalInterests : number
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of data that you want to get as a result?

Comment: @AndriySimonov updated.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you need to build an aggregation pipeline with the operators you have mentioned. Here is a query that returns data you need:

```
db.interests.aggregate([{$project: {professionalInterests: 1,
                                personalInterests: 1,
                                matchedProfessionalInterests: {$setIntersection: [["Finance and Accounting", "Data Modeling"], "$professionalInterests.interestName"]},
                                matchedPersonalInterests: {$setIntersection: [["Music"], "$personalInterests.interestName"]}}},
                    {$project: {professionalInterests: 1,
                                personalInterests: 1,
                                matchedProfessionalInterests: 1,
                                matchedPersonalInterests: 1,
                                matchedProfessionalInterestsCount: {$size: "$matchedProfessionalInterests"},
                                matchedPersonalInterestsCount: {$size: "$matchedPersonalInterests"}}},
                    {$sort: {matchedProfessionalInterestsCount: -1, matchedPersonalInterests: -1}}]);
```

As it is still not clear for me which interest, professional or personal, you want to order results by I have put them both to the $sort stage. You can easily adjust the $sort to your requirements. See the [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) operator documentation.